# How can I change a container component based on a condition avoiding repeating it's content

Tags: angular

I have the component A which is a container. How can I choose ComponentA or ComponentB based on a condition without having to rewrite the content.

```
<ComponentA *ngIf=true>
    ...Content
</ComponentA>

<ComponentB *ngIf=false>
    ...Content
</ComponentB>
```

Here I'm writing ...Content twice. How I can avoid repeating ...Content.

Comment: what do you mean by **`changing the container`**?

Comment: As in the code use ComponentA or ComponentB avoiding  the repetition of ...Content.

Comment: I still don't understand your requirement! can you please elaborate

Comment: What do not you understand? I want to avoid the repetition of the content if I use ngIf I have to write the content(the thing inside the component) twice because it's the same for ComponentA and ComponentB.And that's what I want to avoid the repetition of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of `ng-template` and `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Try:

```
<ComponentA *ngIf=true>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="repeatedContent"></ng-container>
</ComponentA>
<ComponentB *ngIf=false>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="repeatedContent"></ng-container>
</ComponentB>
<ng-template #repeatedContent>
  ...Content
</ng-template>
```

A good resource: https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/